# How to add custom html block to Shopify footer

Tags: shopify, liquid, shopify-template

I was trying to add a custom html field to my Shopify footer. I got found this code on a post from a similar question. My only problem is that is can't display the content, is says that is need to add a new type check. I didn't quite understand where it needs to go. I use the empire theme on Shopify and couldn't seem to find {%- case block.type -%} part.

**This is the code I used: **

Open /sections/footer.liquid then add a new section block to the blocks array, this code should give you a basic starting point:

`{ "type": "html_content", "name": "HTML Content", "settings": [ { "type": "html", "id": "html_area", "label": "Custom HTML", "default": "<div><p>Some HTML content</p></div>" } ] }`

Then to display the content, you need to add a new type check for the html_content type in the `{%- case block.type -%}` block, like so:

`{%- case block.type -%} {%- when 'newsletter' -%} . . . {%- when 'text' -%} . . . {%- when 'link_list' -%} . . . {%- when 'html_content' -%} {{ block.settings.html_area }} {%- endcase -%}`

When you save the change and refresh your theme customizer, you should be able to see a new content type in the footer section.

Comment: If you add the error screenshot, it will help to determine the issue in a better way.

Comment: Helllo I just don't know where the case block.type part needs to go. It is the code that lets it show on the site.